How do I copy values from a column in 1 df to another df based on a condition in Pandas?
I have two pandas data frames
df1 looks like this:



Column A
Column B




1000
Company1


1001
Company2


1002
Company3


1003,1004
Company4



df2 looks like this:



Column A
Column B
Column C




1000
2.1
2.1_Info1


1001
2.3
2.3_Info2


1002
2.1
2.1_Info1


1003
3
3_Info3


1004
6.1
6.1_Info4


1005
2.2
2.2_Info5



What I'm trying to do is check and see if the values from Column A in df1 is in Column A in df2. If it is, I would like to take the information from Column C in df2 and create a new column in df1 with the values from column C in df2 so it would look like this:
output:



Column A
Column B
New Column




1000
Company1
2.1_Info1


1001
Company2
2.3_Info2


1002
Company3
2.1_Info1


1003,1004
Company4
3_Info3, 6.1_Info4


--------
--------




I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you!
I've tried merging, and using for loops but many of my records get discarded and i'm trying to keep all records.

You can explode df1 on 'Column A', merge df2 into it, then groupby on 'Column B' and aggregate the values accordingly.
This assumes df1 doesn't have repeated values in 'Column B'.
df1["Column A"] = df1["Column A"].str.split(",")
df1 = (
    df1.explode("Column A")
    .merge(df2[["Column A", "Column C"]])
    .groupby("Column B", as_index=False)
    .agg({"Column A": ",".join, "Column B": "first", "Column C": ",".join})
)

    Column A  Column B           Column C
0       1000  Company1          2.1_Info1
1       1001  Company2          2.3_Info2
2       1002  Company3          2.1_Info1
3  1003,1004  Company4  3_Info3,6.1_Info4

